# Unable to make ethernet work

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet

I tried to run `sudo ifconfig eno1 up` but still the wired network won't work.

Checking further:

```bsh
$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:93004000-94104fff memory:93000000-94103fff
```

What can I do to make the wired network work?

Comment: Can you install the 8168 driver?  `sudo apt install r8168-dkms`

Comment: @Terrance thanks it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the Realtek 8168 drivers:

```
sudo apt install r8168-dkms
```

Since that is a DKMS driver it will carry over into new kernel updates.  If you ever want to check that run `dkms status` from a terminal window and it will show you your drivers that will carry over.