# Ubuntu 22.04 cable network does not work, only wifi

Tags: networking

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 in dual boot with windows but my wired network doesn't work in Ubuntu. WiFi does work. I tried several tutorials on the internet but none of them work in my case. My system is a fresh installation, I didn't modify any network configuration.

My cable is plugged in and works on Windows so it's not a physical issue or a router issue.

I use Ubuntu with wifi at work, at home I connect the PC with the cable internet (I don't have wifi at home). I start Ubuntu and the internet does not work. I have tried a lot to solve this but nothing works. I am running on Windows to ask for help here because I have internet on the wired connection in Windows. I came back to Ubuntu to take some screenshots of my internet connection, but now the internet works. What is going on? It seems that it began to work again after I started windows and came back to Ubuntu.

(It happened more than once).

[ip addr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CxOi.png)

[dhclient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HMqE.png)

[netplan yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wb8Y.png)

[sudo lshw -C network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOZ0i.png)

about the fast boot, it was already disabled

[fast boot is disabled on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGPvz.png)

My wired settings:

IPv4: automatic(DHCP)
IPv6: Disable

------------ SOLUTION ------------------------------

My internet driver was wrong, it was for 8169 but my hardware is for 8168 driver.

Running sudo apt install r8168-dkms did solve the problem, you will only need to set a password (write it down) and after a reboot use this password to set MOK.

[image: Steps after sudo apt install r8168-dkms and reboot]

Comment: Could this be the issue?https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1434794/edit) your question and add in the output of `sudo lshw -C network` ?  Thank you!

Comment: I have added the sudo lshw -C network,
also I have checked the fast boot, it's disabled, thank you.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1305665/231142 since you have a 8168 NIC where it loaded the 8169 driver, which I have found to not work well at all.

Comment: sudo apt install r8168-dkms Worked!, after set a password, reboot and set the MOK, my cable connection works at work, thank you everyone!

Comment: Go ahead and write your own answer here and I will upvote it.  We are all about Questions and Answers if you want to answer your own.  :)